# May a smooth bijection have a non continuous inverse?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions, derivatives, differential-geometry

Suppose that $f$ is an injective function between open subsets (i.e. with range and domain both open sets) of $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible that $f\in C^{\infty}$, but $f^{-1}\notin C^0$?

Comment: Even in just the $C^0$ category, a continuous injection $f:X \to Y$ with $X$ compact has continuous inverse. Obviously neither the space $\mathbb{R}$ nor the open set in question is compact (and the result doesn't hold in merely locally compact spaces), but their topology is nice enough to patch the local inverse together.

Comment: Slight change (to either the answer or the original question, likely the original question): Injections don't have inverses, so while a smooth bijection is a homeomorphism, a smooth injection is a (topological) embedding, right? (Likely, this is on OP to change injection to bijection because technically injections don't have inverses)

Comment: About my suggested edit: The [edit I suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1220243) is, I think, similar this [approved edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1219893).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) guarantees that such an $f$ is an open-map. So its an open (continuous) bijection, i.e. a homeomorphism.  Invariance of domain for $\mathbb{R}$ is easy to prove:  show that it suffices to check the case where the domain of $f$ is an open interval. Then use intermediate value theorem to show that $f$ injective, continuous implies $f$ is strictly monotonic. If $f$ is not open, then there exists an interval $(a,b) \subset domain(f) $ such that $f((a,b))$ is not open. But $f((a,b))$ is an interval (the continuous image of a connected set is connected), so it must have an endpoint, $d$. Assume $d$ is a right-endpoint. Then if $f(c)=d$ and $ a<x<c<y<b$, we have $f(x), f(y) <f(c)$, contradicting monotonicity. If $d$ is a left endpoint replace $<$ with $>$.

Comment: Slight change (to either the answer or the original question, likely the original question): Injections don't have inverses, so while a smooth bijection is a homeomorphism, a smooth injection is a (topological) embedding, right? (Likely, this is on OP to change injection to bijection because technically injections don't have inverses)